# phantomjs cant run in cgi-bin through browser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

There is a `phantomjs` code in Python, which is running through SSH terminal but not in `cgi-bin` through the browser.
I would be thankful if anyone could help me.
My server OS is `centos` 6.8 and python 2.6 the error_log shows it is from this line

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: in error-log file it gives

Comment: Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f681c785250>> ignored

Comment: and in terminal if i type phantomjs --version it gives correct